# Stability properties of essential geometric morphisms

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, topos-theory, limits-and-colimits

**Notation.**

1. $\mathsf{Topoi}$ is the bicategory of topoi, geometric morphisms and natural transformations between left adjoints.
2. $\mathsf{Topoi}_{\text{ess}}$ is the bicategory of topoi, essential geometric morphisms and natural transformations between left adjoints.
3. $\mathsf{Presh}$ is the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Topoi}$ spanned by presheaf topoi.
4. $\mathsf{Presh}_{\text{ess}}$ Is the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Topoi}_{\text{ess}}$ spanned by presheaf topoi.

**Questions.**

1. Is there a reference for the bicategorical properties of $\mathsf{Topoi}_{\text{ess}}$, $\mathsf{Presh}$, $\mathsf{Presh}_{\text{ess}}$?
2. Which (pseudo)(co)limits are preserved by the inclusion $\mathsf{Presh}_{\text{ess}} \subset \mathsf{Topoi}$? (This is my motivating question.)

Comment: My initial reaction is that class of essential geometric morphisms is in some sense not very "topos-theoretically natural" (at least in comparison to various strengthenings of essentialness, such as local connectedness, etaleness, total connectedness, etc. which _are_ quite natural), and so I don't expect $Topos_{ess}$ to be very well-behaved...

Comment: Though if you restrict to the case where the direct image is fully faithful things improve (because the distinction between essentiality and local connectedness disappears in this case). And a bit is known about presheaves in this case -- see [El Bashir and Velebil](https://www.emis.de/journals/TAC/volumes/10/16/10-16abs.html)

Comment: Shouldn't that be the inverse image functor being full and faithful? Either way, there are both essential connected geometric morphisms and essential inclusions between presheaf toposes which are not locally connected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only a partial answer. With '(co)limit' I will always mean pseudo(co)limit.

1. If $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are Cauchy-complete, then the category of essential geometric morphisms $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{D})$ (and geometric transformations between them) is equivalent to the opposite of the category of functors $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ (and natural transformations between them). This is in “Sketches of an Elephant”, Part A, Example 4.1.4 and Lemma 4.1.5. So in this sense $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess}$ is a full subcategory of $\mathsf{Cat}^\mathrm{co}$, the bicategory of small categories, functors, and natural transformations (with the natural transformations in the opposite direction).
2. By using the above, I think it follows that $$\mathrm{colim}_i\, \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C}_i) ~\simeq~ \mathbf{PSh}(\mathrm{colim}_i \,\mathcal{C}_i)$$ in $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess}$, as long as $\mathrm{colim}_i\, \mathcal{C}_i$ is still Cauchy-complete. In particular, coproducts are computed as $\bigsqcup_i \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C}_i) \simeq \mathbf{PSh}(\bigsqcup_i \mathcal{C}_i)$, and this agrees with the coproduct in $\mathsf{Topoi}$. So the inclusion $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess} \subset \mathsf{Topoi}$ preserves coproducts, in particular the initial object.   Similarly, I think that $$\mathrm{lim} \, \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C}_i) \simeq \mathbf{PSh}(\mathrm{lim}_i \mathcal{C}_i)$$ in $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess}$, as long as $\lim_i \mathcal{C}_i$ is still Cauchy-complete. In particular, the terminal object is $\mathbf{PSh}(1) \simeq \mathbf{Sets}$, just like in $\mathsf{Topoi}$. Also, the product of $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{D})$ is $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D})$. This is also the product in $\mathsf{Topoi}$ (see Pitts, ["On product and change of base for toposes"](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1985__26_1_43_0/)). I don’t know whether $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess} \subset \mathsf{Topoi}$ preserves pullbacks. Examples seem to suggest that pullbacks are preserved, I would be very interested in a proof (here by 'pullback' I mean pseudo-pullback).
   **Update:** here is an example showing that arbitrary products are not preserved. Consider the categories $(\mathcal{C}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\mathcal{C_n}$ given by the discrete category on two objects, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then in $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess}$ the product $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C_n})$ is given by $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{D})$, where $\mathcal{D} \simeq \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{C}_n$ is the discrete category with $2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$ objects. However, in $\mathsf{Topoi}$ the product is $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C_n}) \simeq \mathbf{Sh}(X)$, where $X$ is the Cantor space (the product in the category of toposes/locales agrees with the product in the category of topological spaces, because it is a countable product of completely metrizable spaces, see Isbell, "Atomless parts of spaces").
   **Update 2:** I believe the inclusion $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess} \subset \mathsf{Cat}^\mathrm{co}$ has a left adjoint given by $\mathcal{C} \mapsto \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$. This can be used to show that in $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess}$ the colimit of $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C}_i)$'s, with each $\mathcal{C}_i$ Cauchy-complete, is given by $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{D})$ where $\mathcal{D} = \mathrm{colim}\, \mathcal{C}_i$ is the colimit in $\mathsf{Cat}^\mathrm{co}$ (the category $\mathcal{D}$ does not have to be Cauchy-complete in order for this to work).
   To show that $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{D})$ is also the colimit in $\mathsf{Topoi}$ (so colimits are preserved), we can use that colimits in $\mathsf{Topoi}$ are computed as the limit in $\mathsf{Cat}$ of the corresponding diagram of inverse image functors (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/59862/)). Further, in $\mathsf{Cat}$ we have that $$\mathrm{lim}_i\, \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C}_i) \simeq \mathrm{lim}_i \, \mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C}_i^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Sets}) \simeq \mathrm{Fun}(\mathrm{colim}_i\, \mathcal{C}_i^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Sets}) \\ \simeq \mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Sets}) \simeq \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{D}).$$
   Here we use that $\mathbf{Fun}(-,-)$ sends colimits to limits in the first argument.
   The proof above is based on the answer by Yonatan Harpaz [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/322625).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jens. I will not accept it because it only covers cases I knew.

Comment: Yes, I mostly wanted to write it down for other people reading this (and for myself). I hope there will be more comprehensive answers.

Comment: What do you sense about pushouts? That's the case I am most interested about. I feel like it is preserved, but I did not try proving it by bare hands.

Comment: (I like the remark about the Cantor space, I did not see that).

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I was just looking at it... I think all colimits are preserved! There is an argument for it in the answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/322625/. (I only found the Cantor space example after your comment.)

Comment: I clearly see the connection between the two, but I do not see how that is an argument showing that all colimits are preserved (although I also believe it is true).

Comment: Oh I have the impression that (ignoring for a moment all size issues) the assignment $\mathcal{G} \mapsto \text{Set}^{\mathcal{G}^\circ}$ provides a right adjoint for the inclusion $\text{Presh}_{\text{ess}} \subset \text{Topoi}$. I think I can see the unit and the counit of the adjunction (the unit is the Yoneda embedding). Then one can dodge size issues by studying infinitary pretopoi instead of topoi and small presheaves insted of presheaves.

Comment: If I calculate correctly such an adjunction would give an equivalence $\mathsf{Presh}_\mathrm{ess}(\mathbf{Sets}, \mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{E})) \simeq \mathsf{Topoi}(\mathbf{Sets}, \mathcal{E})$. I think the first category should be $\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op}$, which does not agree with the category of points of $\mathcal{E}$ (maybe it depends on how you deal with the size issues).

Comment: You are right, and I do not believe this is only a size issue problem. Maybe $\mathbf{Psh}(\mathcal{E})$ should be replaced with a similar construction? Something like $\mathbf{Psh}(\mathcal{E})^\mathcal{X}$ for a suitable $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: The assignment $\mathcal{E} \mapsto \mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Pts}(\mathcal{E})^\mathrm{op})$ seems to work, up to size issues?

Comment: Yes I think it works too. I hope there is no issue with the unit, but it should be fixable if it is somehow broken.

Comment: Can we deduce that essential geometric morphisms are the left part of an orthogonal factorization system?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case! We have $\mathcal{L} \perp \mathcal{R}$, for $\mathcal{L}$ the class of essential geometric morphisms between presheaf toposes, and $\mathcal{R}$ the class of morphisms of the form $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Pts}(\mathcal{E})^\mathrm{op}) \to \mathcal{E}$, with $\mathcal{E}$ a Grothendieck topos that has a small category of points.

If $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{E}$ is a geometric morphism, where $\mathcal{E}$ has a small category of points, then it has a unique $(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{R})$-factorization.

Comment: It seems that we found a new facsys in Topoi. That’s cute.

Comment: Yes, I agree! For future reference, the main idea that you need to prove this is that models of a geometric theory in a presheaf topos are the same thing as presheaves of models: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/models+in+presheaf+toposes.

I discussed this with Morgan Rogers and he noticed a big caveat: the right class $\mathcal{R}$ that I gave above is not closed under composition. So it's not an orthogonal factorization system with the usual definition. But we still have $\mathcal{L} \perp \mathcal{R}$ and some unique factorization.